# Personal practice regarding meditation

Tags: theravada

Now I feel lazy to meditate because less thoughts  no breath to observe. once I observe the body ,it isn't  disappears .experience  the vibration of mind and feel there is a connection  between  brain and mind  through blood.

Comment: There is a warning in one of the suttas which says that many stop making effort after they reach a certain level of attainment. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Answer (score 1):

In Buddhist meditation, the primary meditation object is 'letting go' (*vossagga*). The other things (breathing, feelings, etc) are just side-effects or 'signs'. For stream-enterers, letting-go (or little Nibbana) is the meditation object.

> *And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, making it his object to **let go** (vossagga),
>   attains concentration, attains singleness of mind. Quite withdrawn
>   from sensuality, withdrawn from unskillful mental qualities, he enters
>   & remains in the first jhana... [SN 48.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html)*

---

> The Great Way is not difficult for those who have no preferences. When
>   love and hate are both absent everything becomes clear and
>   undisguised. Make the smallest distinction, however, and heaven and
>   earth are set infinitely apart.
>
> If you wish to see the truth then hold no opinions for or against
>   anything. To set up what you like against what you dislike is the
>   disease of the mind.
>
> When the deep meaning of things is not understood the mind's essential
>   peace is disturbed to no avail.
>
> The Way is perfect like vast space where nothing is lacking and
>   nothing is in excess.
>
> Verses on the Faith Mind by Chien-chih Seng-ts'an  Third Zen Patriarch
>   [606AD]